# How to use TFS 2013 Power Tools without visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2013

I installed Team Explorer 2013 and power tools. In the team explorer tools option, I have an export-import WIT option, but they are not working. How to use it or is it compulsory to install visual studio to use WIT?

Answer (score 1):

No, **you can't use TFS2013 Power Tools without VS installed to export or import WIT.**

> Prerequisites
>
> - Best Practices Analyzer: install on the TFS Server (Application Tier)
> - **Process Template Editor: VS Pro and up**
> - Other: Team Explorer or VS Pro
>
> [Source Link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f)

Export or import WIT belongs Process Template Editor is under `TOOLS -> Process Editor-> Work Item Types->Import/Export WIT`

[image]

> **Process Template Editor**
>
> **A Visual Studio add-in**, located under the Tools menu. The Process Template Editor provides a graphical user interface for customizing
>   work items (field, workflow and the form) and process templates. It
>   will not be supported on Win10 with Express for Windows.
>
> [Source Link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1)